# Add Itemlist to guiqwt CurveWidget in Python

Tags: python, qt, plot

I am trying to add an itemlist to a Curvewidget in Python on a GUI that was made using the Qt Designer.

I can't seem to be able to add an Item list to my plot Widget and I don't know where I should start. This is what I've tried:

```
        #-----------initialize Plots----------------------
    self.plot1 = make.curve([], [], title = 'Sine', color = 'r')
    self.plot2 = make.curve([], [], title = 'Cosine', color = 'k')
    self.legend = make.legend('TL')
    self.curvewidget.plot.add_item(self.plot1)
    self.curvewidget.plot.add_item(self.legend)
    self.curvewidget.plot.add_item(self.plot2)

    self.pm = PlotManager(self.curvewidget)
    self.pm.add_plot(self.curvewidget.plot)
    self.itemlist = self.pm.get_itemlist_panel()
    self.pm.add_panel(self.itemlist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by more trial and error. 
All I had to do is modify the code like this:

```
        self.plot1 = make.curve([], [], title = 'Sine', color = 'r')
    self.plot2 = make.curve([], [], title = 'Cosine', color = 'k')
    self.legend = make.legend('TL')
    self.curvewidget.plot.add_item(self.plot1)
    self.curvewidget.plot.add_item(self.legend)
    self.curvewidget.plot.add_item(self.plot2)

    self.pm = PlotManager(self.curvewidget)
    self.pm.add_plot(self.curvewidget.plot)
    self.curvewidget.get_itemlist_panel().show() #add the itemlist panel
```